# Using the MFC dialog editor to add event handlers with a resource-only DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, mfc, resource-dll

Originally my MFC program had one .rc file that includes resources for two languages. But, now I have two .rc files in two separate resource-only dll projects(in the same solution), and use LoadLibrary() and AfxSetResourceHandle() to select language dynamically(I referenced [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24b2tcy0.aspx)).

It seems working well, but one problem is that I cannot use dialog editor properly for dialogs in resource-only dll projects. It shows dialogs normally but I cannot add event handler by double-clicking a control or by using property menu. Is there any way to connect code and resource files which are in separate projects in the same solution?

**EDIT**:

I changed the approach slightly. Instead of creating new RC files in separate resource projects, I created them in the main project and excluded them from the build. And I made them to be referenced by separate resource projects.

One important point was that I added `#include "resource.h"` into **Read-only symbol directives** of each RC file(You can do this by right-clicking the RC file in Resource View and choosing **Resource Includes** item). `"resource.h"` here is the one that is related to the main project's original RC file which has resources for multiple languages. I don't know why I should add it, but it seems necessary for satellite dll to be working well.

One problem remaining is how to maintain that multiple RC files. For adding resources, if I should maintain original RC file and its resource.h file, I might have to add resources first into the original RC file and then copy them into every language specific RC file. Is this right method, or can I go on without the original RC file?

Answer (score 1):

Include the RC file for this resource only DLL into the project too. But exclude it from the build.

If you have two resource files. Use resource file in a different way:

1. Create a stand alone program with a normal MFC resource file...
2. Use language tags for all dialog resources internally
3. Than use this resource in a second project to build the satellite DLL
4. Set the resource compiler defines so that the resources tagged with the specfic language are not included.

Comment: If I include the RC file into the project that includes source code, then how can I exclude the RC file from the build?

Comment: Right-click .rc file in solution explorer, under 'general' set 'excluded from build' to 'yes'.

Comment: I included the RC file from resource dll project into the project that has source code(maybe just reference not copied) but still I can't add event handler using dialog editor.

Comment: Do you have more than one resource file? Changed my answer.